# Pass variable in awk inside command substitution

Tags: bash, variables, awk, command-substitution

I am new at this and is learning how to get the variable. How do i get print variable parts right inside command substitution? Thanks.

```
echo "Enter number of parts:"
read parts
echo "Enter filename:"
read filename

LINES=$(wc -l $filename | awk '{print $1/$parts}' OFMT="%0.0f")

echo $LINES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is twofold. First, bash won't expand variables in single quotes, so `$parts` is passed literally to `awk`. You should use double quotes instead. That, however, brings up a different issue. Bash is expanding the variables *before* calling `awk`:

```
LINES=$(wc -l $filename | awk "{print $1/$parts}" OFMT="%0.0f")
                                      -- ------
                                       |    |-> $parts as defined in
                                       |         your script
                                       |------> $1, the first positional 
                                                parameter of your bash script.
```

So, in order to use the actual first field of the file, you need to escape the `$1`:

```
LINES=$(wc -l $filename | awk '{print \$1/$parts}' OFMT="%0.0f")
```

Or pass the variable to awk explicitly:

```
LINES=$(wc -l $filename | awk '{print $1/parts}' OFMT="%0.0f" parts=$parts)
```

Comment: Thanks. i learnt more.

Answer (score 2):

Pass your `bash` variable in with `-v`.

Also, you can let `awk` count the lines in the file for you - it will know that at the end in the `NR` variable...

```
awk -v p=$parts 'END{print int(NR/p)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
LINES=$(wc -l $filename | awk -v PART=$parts '{print $1/PART}' OFMT="%0.0f")
```